# installation of gazebo turtlebot simulator

Tags: ros, gazebo, installation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I apologise in advance I'm totally new to this. I'm trying to install turtlebot with gazebo simulator.

I followed the instructions here:
http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world

I typed

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps ros-indigo-turtlebot-rviz-launchers
```

into the terminal but received  these errors.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot-apps
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot-rviz-launchers
```

How do I get the packages? Thanks a lot in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205918/installation-of-gazebo-turtlebot-simulator/) by [JamesAngsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21979/jamesangsy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TurtleBot for indigo has not been officially released. It's being staged at the moment. [see this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/ros-sig-turtlebot/CA%2B9kZcbkW%3DFWsyYpMrG_PpD0bvaDWY%2B_rmqqwfzsjxE%2BV80xtg%40mail.gmail.com)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you followed the appropriate ROS [Installation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation)? Those packages have been released, so after setting up the repositories, you should be able to install them.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1